# How to use EZDXF Library to add an image with different scales?

Tags: python, dxf, ezdxf

I notice 'The IMAGE entity is like a block reference, you can use it multiple times to add the image on different locations with different scales and rotations.' in the introduction of class 'Image'(see : https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/master/dxfentities/image.html ).But I can not find any parameter to resize the image.
For example,the original size of the image is (3000x1691),and when I use AutoCAD to load the dxf file with this image,I hope its size is (101x57).Could anybody tell me how to do that?Sorry for my poor English.
Here is my code:

```
dwg = ezdxf.readfile('AC1015.dxf')# 2010

msp = dwg.modelspace()

imageWidth, imageHeight = get_image_size(imageFilePath)

#create layout
dwg.layers.new(name=layoutName, dxfattribs={'color': layoutColor})
my_layout = dwg.layers.get(layoutName)

my_image_def = dwg.add_image_def(filename=imageFilePath, size_in_pixel=(imageWidth,imageHeight))
my_image_def.dxf.resolution_units = 2

image_ = msp.add_image(insert=ucs.origin, size_in_units=(1,1),
                           image_def=my_image_def, rotation=0, dxfattribs={'layer': layoutName})

#save file
dwg.saveas(dxfoutfile)
```

I tried to change 'size_in_pixel' and 'size_in_units',but it didn't work.
I 'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: I found that Image.dxf.u_pixel and Image.dxf.v_pixel can not only change the direction but also the size of the image, so my problem has been solve.Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add your own answer?